# Cancel Token from infinite Parallel.Foreach loop from an event

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have write some code, where i am using Parallel.Foreach for few items to work parallel with infinite loop i.e working fine after every 60 sec.

But here my message can be change by the user at any time and i need to re-process with new message.
For this, i need to cancel the infinite Parallel.Foreach loop to reprocess the updated message.

when i am trying to reprocess the main method its working fine for new message, but its running twice because the previous scheduled tasks is not canceled. I am assuming i need to cancel process from Parrallel.Foreach loop and re-run again for updated message with new schedule.

So can anyone help me to cancel the queued task that is already scheduled for next 60 second.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<RealTimeMessage> messages = GetRealTimeMessage();
        Parallel.ForEach(messages, (message) =>
        {
            processMessage(message);
        });

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

private static async void processMessage(RealTimeMessage message)
{
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
            await Task.Run(() => ProceesRequest(message));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Critical error");
    }
}

private static List<RealTimeMessage> GetRealTimeMessage()
{
    List<RealTimeMessage> realTimeMessages = new List<RealTimeMessage>();
    realTimeMessages.Add(new RealTimeMessage { MessageText = "Message 4", IntervalTime = "1", MessageType = "AIDX", TimeOfDay = "" });
    realTimeMessages.Add(new RealTimeMessage { MessageText = "Message 5", IntervalTime = "2", MessageType = "AMSX", TimeOfDay = "" });

    return realTimeMessages;
}
private static void ProceesRequest(RealTimeMessage message)
{
 // do domething
}
```

Comment: Why are you starting a task in the while loop?

Comment: To run a method after each 60 second delay, delay time can be vary i mean its configurable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This is a misuse of `Parallel.ForEach`, use `Task.WhenAll` instead
2. Don't start a `Task` in ProcessMessage (this could be intentional, however it looks like a mistake).
3. Use a `CancellationToken` to *cancel* a *task*
4. Don't use `async void` unless it's for an event
5. Use standard casing for method names
6. Don't use `while(true)` use `while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)`

When all things are considered, it would look something like this

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
   var ts = new CancellationTokenSource();

   var messages = GetRealTimeMessage();
   var tasks = messages.Select(x => ProcessMessage(x, ts.Token));

   Console.WriteLine("Press any key to cancel tasks")
   Console.ReadKey();

   ts.Cancel();
   await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

   Console.WriteLine("All finished");
   Console.ReadKey(); 
}

private static async Task ProcessMessage( RealTimeMessage message, CancellationToken token )
{
   try
   {
      while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
      {
         await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60), token);
         ProcessRequest(message);
      }
   }
   catch (OperationCanceledException)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Operation Cancelled");
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Critical error: " +  ex.Message);
   }
}
```

To *cancel* your *tasks*, just call `ts.Cancel()`.

Comment: When i am not writing it, in loop its complete all task, but i want to run my method after each 60 sec, It should behave like a scheduler.

Comment: @radhey_mishra it runs ProcessRequest with a 60 delay repeatedly until its cancelled

Comment: I have debug it, and it gets exit from: await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60), token);

Comment: @radhey_mishra you can only use a token once. then you have to create a new one. There no other reason why `Task.Delay` would exit the function

Comment: when i am giving 60 sec of delay for next run...its going in sleep mode and gets exit.

Comment: @radhey_mishra its exits because `token.IsCancellationRequested = true`, you need to make a fresh new token

Comment: Thanks @Michael : I have achieved my goal.